# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity3d, классы, list

```
   [System.Serializable]
public class allwc {
    int dx = 2;
    List<wc> lst;
    public  allwc(List<GameObject> allworker) {
        List<wc> lst = new List<wc>();
        for (int i = 0; i < allworker.Count; i++) {
            wc wcone = new wc();
            wcone.x = allworker[i].transform.position.x;
            wcone.y = allworker[i].transform.position.y;
            wcone.food = allworker[i].GetComponent<worker1>().food;
            wcone.mas = new int[3];
            wcone.mas[0] = 22;
            wcone.mas[1] = 33;
            wcone.mas[2] = 44;
            lst.Add(wcone);
        }
    }
    public List<wc> getallwc() {
        return lst;
    }

    public int getdx()
    {
        return dx;
    }

}

public void savegame() {
    print("save");
    allwc allwcOne = new allwc(allworker);
    List<wc> lst = new List<wc>();
    lst = allwcOne.getallwc();
    print(allwcOne.getallwc()[0].x);
}
```

print(allwcOne.getallwc()[0].x) -  в чем ошибка почему он не может его найти ?

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что в `allwcOne.getallwc()[0]` ничего нет (возможно список пуст),  и взять `x` не у кого.

А вот почему там пусто и что происходит на каждом шаге, в том числе складывается ли вообще что-либо в список - можно посмотреть в отладчике IDE

Answer (score 0):

Решение такое  заменил List lst = new List(); на lst = new List();
видимо он создает внутри функции локальную переменную и не записывает значение в поле класса.